# Infinite Scroll Remove the paginator when we're done

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I need remove the paginator when we're done like at the demo http://www.infinite-scroll.com/trigger.html

```
    // remove the paginator when we're done.
    $(document).ajaxError(function(e,xhr,opt){
      if (xhr.status == 404) $('a#next').remove();
    });
```

But this code doesn't work. I have mentioned that at the demo the version of Infinite Scroll is 1.5.100504 but the latest versiont that I have downloaded here is 2.0b2.110713 So, any help please?

Maybe this can help me:

```
state: {
    isDuringAjax: false,
    isInvalidPage: false,
    isDestroyed: false,
    isDone: false, // For when it goes all the way through the archive.
    isPaused: false,
    currPage: 1
  },
```

?

Comment: Are you sending a 404 status code back when you can't find more content? It would help to see the code *you're* working with an not a working demo on the vendor site.

Comment: Actually demo site is working well. What do u mean exactly?

Comment: I want to see your broken site, not the working tech demo.

Comment: Sure here is my site http://layot.prestatrend.com/?page_id=322

Comment: You have no element called `<a id="next">`, you have an element called `<a class="next">`... Moreover, the 'MORE' button you use is `not` called `next`, you use `load-more`, so it would be `$('a#load-more').remove();`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site never sends back a 404 http status code therefore this line will never work:

```
if (xhr.status == 404) jQuery('#load-more').find('.text').html('No more posts to load.').end().delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

The "No more posts to load" message is coming from the "finishedMsg" property of your infinitescroll initialization.

If you were to add

```
finished: function() {
    if (this.options.state.isDone) {
        $('#load-more').remove();
    }
},
```

to the loading property of the config:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '#nav-pagination-load-more',
            nextSelector: '#nav-pagination-load-more .next',
            itemSelector: '.hentry',
            loading: {
                selector: '#load-more',
                finishedMsg: 'No more posts to load.',
                img: 'http://cdn.moozpaper.com/lucidpress/wp-content/themes/lucidpress/images/loading_small.gif',
                // like so: ==============================
                finished: function() {
                    if (this.options.state.isDone) {
                        $('#load-more').remove();
                    }
                }, 
                msgText: ''
            },
            behavior: 'local'
        },
```

it should probably do what you need. It's hard to say though since this version of the plugin is not documented very well.

Comment: You have it in the wrong place... it needs to be inside the `loading` property, same level as `finishedMsg`

Comment: Yep, but now it removes my button just after first click... Maybe this can help me - see updated post.

Comment: I was worried about that... the property names are a bit misleading since `finishedMsg` only appears when there is nothing left but `finished` executes when it's done loading the first time.

Comment: I've edited my answer to update the function, maybe that will work. if that doesn't work try changing `this.options` to `opts`

Comment: Still no luck what about this: errorCallback: function () { }, ?

Comment: This works!!! errorCallback: function () { jQuery('#load-more').find('.text').html('No more posts to load.').end().delay(2000).fadeOut(); }

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to plugin this in the start code but I just edited it directly.

Where you see the following:

```
opts.loading.start = opts.loading.start || function() {
```

add this
    opts.loading.msg = $('');

to make

```
opts.loading.start = opts.loading.start || function() {
$(opts.navSelector).hide();
opts.loading.msg = $('<div id="">');
```

on the dev version it's around line 155.   This basically shorts out the loading box without destroying callbacks etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the script to be executed in the finishedMsg option for loading:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
  ...
  loading: {
    finishedMsg: "<div class='infinite-scroll-finished'>No more articles to load!</div>
                  <script type='text/javascript'> $('#infinity-start').hide(); </script>"
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `errorCallback` option:-

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    errorCallback: function(){ 
        $('#load-more').remove()
    }
});
```